# SQL Server - How to remove trailing zeros from milliseconds in datetime2 data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime2

How can I use any cast or convert function to remove trailing zeros from milliseconds in datetime2 data type.

For example, I have these data:

```
2018-02-17 13:26:55.033000
2018-02-17 12:37:12.300000
2018-02-17 14:55:30.110000
```

I want to change it to:

```
2018-02-17 13:26:55.033
2018-02-17 12:37:12.3
2018-02-17 14:55:30.11
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `datetime` and not `datetime2`. Or use `CAST()` or `CONVERT()` to convert to datetime

Comment: @Squirrel I have used this convert(datetime, convert(datetime2, '2018-02-17 12:37:12.300000')) but it doesn't work. The result is 2018-02-17 12:37:12.300.

Comment: you want to remove any trailing zero also ? Formatting should be done on your front end application where the data is display, not in SQL Server. Removing any trailing zero would means, returning varchar to your front end application and not datetime anymore

Answer (score 1):

```
-- Sample DDL/DML statements:
declare @tbl table (dt datetime2)
insert into @tbl values 
('2018-02-17 13:26:55.033000'),
('2018-02-17 12:37:12.300000'),
('2018-02-17 14:55:30.110000')

-- Use this recursive CTE to trim trailing zeros.
-- The dt col is the original value, the rn col is a 
-- recursive incrementor, and the vc col is the varchar
-- representation of the datetime2.
;with cte as 
(
    select dt, 1 as rn, cast(dt as varchar(100)) vc 
    from @tbl
    union all 
    select dt, rn + 1, SUBSTRING(vc, 1, len(vc) - 1)
    from cte 
    where SUBSTRING(reverse(vc), 1, 1) = '0'
)
select vc 
from cte 
where rn = (select max(rn) from cte c where dt = cte.dt)

vc
2018-02-17 14:55:30.11
2018-02-17 12:37:12.3
2018-02-17 13:26:55.033
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. AS Squirrel mentioned this will return nvarchar and not datetime.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
    (
        YourColumn DATETIME2
    );

INSERT INTO #temp ( YourColumn )
VALUES ( GETDATE() -- YourColumn - datetime2
    );

SELECT *
FROM   #temp;

SELECT REVERSE(
           SUBSTRING(
               REVERSE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), YourColumn, 121)) ,
               PATINDEX(
                   '%[1-9]%' , REVERSE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), YourColumn, 121))),
               LEN(YourColumn)
               - PATINDEX(
                     '%[1-9]%' ,
                     REVERSE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), YourColumn, 121))) + 1)) AS YourColumnTrim
FROM   #temp;

DROP TABLE #temp;
```

Result:

```
+-----------------------------+
|         YourColumn          |
+-----------------------------+
| 2018-07-18 13:22:54.1530000 |
+-----------------------------+

+-------------------------+
|     YourColumnTrim      |
+-------------------------+
| 2018-07-18 13:22:54.153 |
+-------------------------+
```

Comment: the data type is datetime2 not strig

Comment: sorry, forgot to cast it to string.

Comment: Works without casting on Datetime2 to varchar though.

Comment: that is because the implicit conversion of `datetime2` to `varchar` is using style `121`. It is better to explicit specify the style when converting data type

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Get the millisecond part, reverse it, convert it to INT and again Reverse. Please try-.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 

    GETDATE() CompleteDate,

    CAST ( GETDATE() AS DATE ) DtPart   

    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE () , 24 )  TmPart

    ,REVERSE(CAST(REVERSE(DATEPART(MILLISECOND,GETDATE())) AS INT)) MilliPart   
)
SELECT CompleteDate 
    , CONCAT( DtPart, ' ' , TmPart , '.' , MilliPart ) [DateTimeWithOutZero]
FROM CTE


CompleteDate            DateTimeWithOutZero
----------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2018-07-18 14:22:52.190 2018-07-18 14:22:52.19

(1 row affected)
```